# How do you concatenate two database fields together in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

Below is my code:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
      echo "
  <tr>
      <td>{$row['TeacherForename'].$row['TeacherSurname']}</td>
       <td>{$row['StudentForename'].$row['StudentSurname']}</td>
  </tr>";
    }
```

I want TeacherForname and TeacherSurname to concatenate with each other and StudentForename and StudentSurname and when I researched it says use the . syntax to concatenate but it doesn't work.

How are you suppose to do it?

Comment: An alternative would be to use MySQL's [CONCAT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
      echo "
  <tr>
      <td>{$row['TeacherForename']}{$row['TeacherSurname']}</td>
       <td>{$row['StudentForename']}{$row['StudentSurname']}</td>
  </tr>";
    }
```

As long as you do that in the string context - `.` cannot be treated as php concatenation operator. So just place two variables together and that's it.